# How to make SwiftUI List scroll on tvOS

Tags: swiftui, tvos, swiftui-list

```
struct ContentView: View {

    private let showList = [
        "The Flintstones",
        "The Cosby Show",
        "The Fresh Prince of Bel Air",
        "Full House",
        "Seinfeld",
        "Friends",
        "The Big Bang Theory",
        "How I Met Your Mother",
        "Grey's Anatomy",
        "The Office",
        "Law & Order",
        "I Love Lucy",
        "Family Guy",
        "The Simpsons",
        "24"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List(showList,id: \.self) { element in
            Text(element)
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I am trying to use List in a tvOS app, but when I run the app, the list does not scroll. This list scrolls fine when the same code is run on iOS.

How can I make this list scroll on tvOS?

Answer (score 1):

In TVOS only focusable Elements can be selected via the remote control. So you need to make your list elements focusable. One way would be to make a list of buttons:

```
      List {
        ForEach(showList ?? []) { show in
          Button(action: {}) {
          Text(show)
          }
          .buttonStyle(CardButtonStyle())
        }
      }
```

Comment: if i scroll fast the focused item will go off screen and it takes a second or two for the scroll to gain on my swipe and show the selected item, is that solvable ?